# Making fillRect fill dynamically from right to left

Tags: java, awt

Hi i am currently working on a Java app and i have to draw a little using Canvas, Graphics etc..

So if i click a point and drag it across, it should have a line drawn in between (Think of drawing a line in paint).

I am currently using fillRect and the question is, is there a way to fillRect from right to left? Or do i have to explicitly create a workaround for this?

Answer (score 2):

`fillRect()` method needs four arguments, `x`, `y`, `width`, `height`. What you should do is just compute the values of those arguments. If you want to draw fillRect from right to left, you just need to decrease `x` and increase `width` perhaps as your mouse move. That's it.

Comment: It was that simple... Thanks for the help; Maybe i should take a break after working for 9 hours (:

Answer (score 1):

To add to ntalbs excellent answer (+1).

Basically, when the user clicks a point, you need to store that as the anchor point.  When they drag the mouse, you need to determine in which direction the mouse has dragged.

If the click.x > drag.x, the the drag.x becomes the x parameter for your rectangle, otherwise it's the click.x.

Width and height are simple determine as the difference between the click and drag points (taking into consideration which is larger ;))